# Select query in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a very curious question.
We have query to select records from table based on some condition. In general the syntax for the query is as below

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE COLUMNNAME='VALUE';
```

Now the question is that will this query will work if we interchange the position of `COLUMNNAME` and `'VALUE'`.

Comment: +1 For asking a simple question I would never have though to consider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it will. =)

Why did you not just try?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The following will work:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE 'VALUE' = COLUMNNAME;
```

Answer (score 2):

In fact, in Oracle at least, you can do some twisted but somewhat useful things like:

```
select *
from tablename
where 'VALUE' in (field1, field2, field3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE 'VALUE' = COLUMNNAME;
```

I tested it, it works on MSSQL Servver 2008

Comment: I knew it works, but i am sure that most of the people are not aware of this.. so thought good way to make people aware of it. :)

Comment: You are right, I would never have thought of it until I read your question ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE 'VALUE' = COLUMNNAME;
```

if write something like this.. it'll work for sure..